# Post response iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cakephp, post, token

I'm working on an iOS app and I created an API using cakephp in which I implemented JWT for the auth. I verified via postman if it works, and it works fine [image]

The problem that I had is that when I tried to login via iOS using a post method I don't got the token .

here is my code on iOS

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8765/api/accounts/token"];
NSMutableURLRequest *rq = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[rq setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSData *jsonData = [@"{ \"mail_address\": test@gmail.com,\"password\": 1234 }" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[rq setHTTPBody:jsonData];

[rq setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[rq setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: rq returningResponse: nil error: nil];
NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"POST sent! %@",strData);
```

Comment: Start by supplying values for `returningResponse` and `error` and see if something went wrong.  Also are you running this code on the simulator or a real device?  Your URL is "localhost" so that won't work if you are on a real device.  You using "HTTP", so you will also need to disable ATS.

Comment: Ok it's getting more clear. As a response I have a HTML page. 
The error is null. I was looking at the html code and I found my token but it's not JSON how am I suppose to get it ?!

Comment: Well, looking at your screenshot, there is JSON there, but there is some HTML above it warning you about your php code.  Perhaps fix that first.

Comment: Yes but I displayed as html in postman if I switch to json it's fine

Comment: I don't think that is the case; If there is HTML data there then the whole document isn't valid JSON.  I suspect you aren't setting your response header to `application/json` on your PHP side.  Also you can look at `NSJSONSerializer` class on ios to create and parse JSON for you.

Comment: Looks like your server is returning HTML. iOS doesn't deal with HTML they deal with JSON. Postman is running in your browser so obviously, your browser understands HTML. Can you tell your server to render JSON ? Also I don't know if CakePHP is the same but in Ruby on Rails, you need to start your server using a special pattern `rails server -b 0.0.0.0` and sometimes you need to enable some config setting to allow mobile apps to talk to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, 
on my iOS code it miss this

```
[rq setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
```